# Dos Interrupt Handler Locks Up Program

Tags: c, assembly, game-engine, dos

I'm trying to make a simple game engine/library for creating my own DOS games.  I'm currently working on getting input working correctly. The problem I'm  having is that my custom ISR that handles int 9 (keyboard input) locks up my  program.

*NOTE: I got it working by using my compiler's _dos_getvect() and _dos_setvect(); however, I don't know why my own custom getInterruptVector() and setInterruptVector() do not work. I would be most appreciative if somebody could explain why.*

*Look at "interrupt_hooker.c" for the code in question.*

### main.c

```
#include "input.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    hookKeyboardISR();

    unsigned char i = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("%i", 1);
        //i = getKey(SCAN_ESC);
        //printf("%i", i);
    }

    unhookKeyboardISR();
    return 0;
}
```

### input.h

```
#ifndef INPUT_H_INCLUDED
#define INPUT_H_INCLUDED

#include "scan_codes.h"

void            hookKeyboardISR();
void            unhookKeyboardISR();

unsigned char   getKey(unsigned char scan_code);

unsigned char   isExtended();

#endif // INPUT_H_INCLUDED
```

### input.c

```
#include "input.h"
#include "interrupt_hooker.h"

#ifndef NULL
#define NULL ((void*)0)
#endif // NULL

unsigned char key_array[MAX_SCAN_CODES] = {0};
unsigned char extended_key = 0;

void __interrupt (*oldKeyboardISR)() = NULL;


unsigned char getKey(unsigned char scan_code)
{
    return key_array[scan_code];
}

unsigned char isExtended()
{
    return extended_key;
}

void __interrupt keyboardISR()
{
    unsigned char scan_code = 0;

    unsigned char temp = 0;
    scan_code = inp(0x60);
    outp(0x61,(temp = inp(0x61)) | 0x80);
    outp(0x61,temp);
    /*asm
    {
        in  al, 60h         //get scan code from keyboard controller
        mov scan_code, al   //put it in scan_code

        in  al, 61h
        or  al, 80h
        out 61h, al
        xor al, 80h
        out 61h, al
    }*/

    switch(scan_code)
    {
    //if extended code
    case 0xe0:
        extended_key = 1;
        break;

    case 0xe1:
        break;

    default:
        //check if break code
        if(scan_code & 0x80){
            scan_code &= 0x7f;

            //set key to released
            key_array[scan_code] = 0;

        }
        else{
            //set key to pressed
            key_array[scan_code] = 1;
        }

        extended_key = 0;
        break;
    }

    //send EOI
    outp(0x20, 0x20);
    /*asm
    {
        sti
        mov al, 20h
        out 20h, al
    }*/
}

void hookKeyboardISR()
{
    if(oldKeyboardISR == NULL){
        getInterruptVector(0x09, oldKeyboardISR);
        setInterruptVector(0x09, keyboardISR);
    }
}

void unhookKeyboardISR()
{
    if(oldKeyboardISR != NULL){
        setInterruptVector(0x09, oldKeyboardISR);
        oldKeyboardISR = NULL;
    }
}
```

### interrupt_hooker.h

```
#ifndef INTERRUPT_HOOKER_H_INCLUDED
#define INTERRUPT_HOOKER_H_INCLUDED

void getInterruptVector(unsigned char int_number, void __interrupt (*isr)());

void setInterruptVector(unsigned char int_number, void __interrupt (*isr)());

#endif // INTERRUPT_HOOKER_H_INCLUDED
```

### interrupt_hooker.c

```
void getInterruptVector(unsigned char int_number, void __interrupt (*isr)())
{
    asm
    {
        cli
        mov al, int_number
        mov ah, 35h
        int 21h

        mov word ptr [isr], bx
        mov word ptr [isr+2], es
        sti
    }
}

void setInterruptVector(unsigned char int_number, void __interrupt (*isr)())
{
    asm
    {
        cli
        mov dx, word ptr [isr+2]
        mov ds, dx
        mov dx, word ptr [isr]

        mov al, int_number
        mov ah, 25h
        int 21h
        sti
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mov dx, word ptr [isr]` might try to use `ds` that you just clobbered unless `isr` gets resolved to `bp+offset` in which case it will use `ss` and that should be good. Also, I guess the compiler won't be happy that you destroyed `ds`.

A safer code could be:

```
cli
push ds
mov al, int_number
mov ah, 25h
mov dx, word ptr [isr]
mov ds, word ptr [isr+2]
int 21h
pop ds
sti
```

Your `getInterruptVector` is broken because it's missing a level of indirection - you are just modifying the parameter which is pass-by-value in C. You'd have to invoke it as `getInterruptVector(0x09, &oldKeyboardISR);` (notice the `&`) and of course dereference it in your function, something like:

```
    mov al, int_number
    mov ah, 35h
    int 21h

    mov di, word ptr [isr]
    mov [di], bx
    mov [di+2], es
```

(That's assuming a 16 bit near pointer, not sure what your memory model is.)

Comment: Yes, your asm code seems to work well. Thank you. The only problem is that `getInterruptVector(0x09, &oldKeyboardISR)` gives me an error. The error message is "Error: need explicit cast for function parameter 2 to get." I really have no idea what this means. I am using Digital Mars C and compiling for the Small  memory model, btw.

Comment: You also need to add a `*` in the function definition of course, I skipped that part. Ie. `void getInterruptVector(unsigned char int_number, void __interrupt (**isr)())` Or, you know, you could just make it return the value instead of passing an output pointer argument.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. Still the same error. I guess I could return a function pointer, but I prefer this way because it's more consistent. Being stubborn like this forces me to learn things, and that's the whole purpose of this DOS project. The problem seems to be linked to `&oldKeyboardISR` because I can pass it to either getInterruptVector() or setInterruptVector() and it gives me the error, but when I pass `&keyboardISR` it works just fine.

Comment: Also, I don't think this can be pass by value, because I am, by definition, passing a pointer to a function.

Comment: You probably forgot to update both the prototype in the header and the implementation in the .c file. Note this applies to the `get` only. All arguments in C are pass by value. If you want to modify a pointer you will need to pass a pointer to it, hence double indirection.

Comment: Ok, yes, I understand now! Thank you very much!